# string.Contains results in => HRESULT: 0x80070002

Tags: c#, build, mono, xamarin

**Sitrep:** I've got a parsing function that parses a number of texts in an array to values. I do the same kind of parsing several times in a row, and the first 3 work, while the last two throw errors in Xamarin when I try to build. I've been over it several times, and can't figure out what's wrong with them.

## The Error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorDebug.NativeApi.ICorDebug.CreateProcess(String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, Int32 bInheritHandles, UInt32 dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, String lpCurrentDirectory, STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation, CorDebugCreateProcessFlags debuggingFlags, ICorDebugProcess& ppProcess)
at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorDebug.CorDebugger.CreateProcess(String applicationName, String commandLine, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes, Boolean inheritHandles, Int32 creationFlags, IntPtr environment, String currentDirectory, STARTUPINFO startupInfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION& processInformation, CorDebugCreateProcessFlags debuggingFlags)
at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorDebug.CorDebugger.CreateProcess(String applicationName, String commandLine, String currentDirectory, IDictionary`2 environment, Int32 flags)
at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Win32.CorDebuggerSession.<>c__DisplayClass5.<OnRun>b__4()
at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Win32.MtaThread.Run(Action ts)
at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Win32.CorDebuggerSession.OnRun(DebuggerStartInfo startInfo)
at Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerSession.<>c__DisplayClass11.<Run>b__f()
```

Now I've looked through this error, and I've read it, but I don't understand enough of it to make anything of it. To me, it looks like Xamarin can't find a file it needs to debug the build, so I tried a repair install on Xamarin, but that didn't help.

## The Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
        string s = lines[i];
        bool p;
// Some other parsing stuff

        else if (s.Contains("Melee:")) {
            int myMelee;
            p = int.TryParse(s.Replace("Melee:", "").Trim(), out myMelee);
            currentMek.melee = myMelee;
            mekMelee.Value = currentMek.melee;
        }
        else if (s.Contains("Guns:")) {
            int myGuns;
            p = int.TryParse(s.Replace("Guns:", "").Trim(), out myGuns);
            currentMek.guns = myGuns;
            mekGuns.Value = currentMek.guns;
        }
        else if (s.Contains("Cannons:")) {
            int myCannons;
            p = int.TryParse(s.Replace("Cannons:", "").Trim(), out myCannons);
            currentMek.cannons = myCannons;
            mekCannons.Value = currentMek.cannons;
        }
        //causing problems from here down
        else if (s.Contains("Missiles:")) {
            int myMissiles;
            p = int.TryParse(s.Replace("Missiles:", "").Trim(), out myMissiles);
            currentMek.missiles = myMissiles;
            mekMissiles.Value = currentMek.missiles;
        }
        else if (s.Contains("Rockets:")) {
            int myRockets;
            p = int.TryParse(s.Replace("Rockets:", "").Trim(), out myRockets);
            currentMek.rockets = myRockets;
            mekRockets.Value = currentMek.rockets;
        }
}
```

If I remove or comment out the last two if elses, all is well. Why is that?

Comment: On which line is the error being thrown?

Comment: It's thrown as an exception when I build the project, but Xamarin doesn't tell me where or what exactly. I've tracked it down to the "s.Contains("Missiles:"), as long as the if statement is empty. Sometimes, if I change the string "Missiles:" to something else, like "Miss" it will work, but only if the if statement is empty. It seems to be related to the string.Contains and string.Replace methods in mono, I guess?

Comment: Have you tried running code without debugger?

Comment: No, that hadn't really occurred to me. I suppose you mean like a release build rather than a debug build? I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: Alright, the release build works, but the debug doesn't? What the hell is that about? And how do I, or CAN I fix it?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible test case?  Submit it as a bug to Xamarin - bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some error in your array , try to check if the rows you are looking for , is actually in your array , and error might be for **ArrayOutOfIndex** , because several times visual studio returns errors incorrectly mostly in VS2012. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin instead of VS, and I specifically create an array that's too large to hold my data. I only ever put 13 strings in, but the entry is initialized to a length of 20.